# Custom Post Type or just Post Categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm using WordPress as a Content Management System.

I currently have a few different Custom Post Types: `featured`, `species`, `answers`, `forums` and `glossary`.

These are all bespoke and wouldn't work with the default Posts functionality.

However, I've also got three separate types of Post which require the same functionality but are displayed on three separate areas of the website: `news`, `articles`, `blogs`.

My question is this: **should I just use categories to display these posts, or should I create Custom Post Types for them?**.

At the moment I'm using categories, but it's causing a couple of issues:

- As default a `blog`, an `article` or a `news` post all have the same URL format: `website.com/post_slug`
- I'd prefer it to be `website.com/news/post_slug`, `website.com/blog/post_slug` etc.

...

- I'd like to be able to use a URL structure such as `website.com/blog/author/name` or `website.com/author/name/blogs` to view only that author's blog-type posts.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping News, Blog, and Article all as post categories is a good idea.

To achieve `domain.com/news/bob-smith/bobs-news-post` set your Permalinks to be `/%category%/%author%/%postname%/`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean, by default, my URLs would include the author name? I'm not really interested in that - I want the URLs to be `website.com/blogs/post_slug` but I also want the author to have their own URL (`website.com/author/blogs/name`) displaying all of their posts for that category.

Comment: You're asking a lot for the built-in functionality. You will probably have to actually learn rewrite .htaccess script to achieve what you want.